# How would I configure yargs to take a single input file and optional output file?

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface, yargs

I'm playing with [yargs](https://yargs.js.org) as would like to configure the following command line options:

```
Usage: myapp <source file> [destination file]
```

No options, no commamnds, etc. Just takes a file path to read from and an optional one to write to. What's the yarg config that gets me that *and* gives me all the nice documentation?

Seems like I either need to use an option or a command. Can't I just pass in the file argument on its own?

Couldn't see how to do this with commander either. Trying to trade up from `process.argv`, but stuck at the first hurdle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to get the first and second parameters:

```
var argv=require('yargs').argv
var source=argv._[0]
var dest=argv._[1]
```

Or even a better way:

```
const argv = require("yargs").command(
  "$0 <source file> [destination file]",
  "the default command",
  () => {},
  function({ sourcefile, destinationfile }) {
    console.log({ sourcefile, destinationfile })
  },
).argv
```

`$0` is the default command.
The output should be:

```
myapp.js <source file> [destination file]

the default command

Options:
  --help     Show help                                                 [boolean]
  --version  Show version number                                       [boolean]

Not enough non-option arguments: got 0, need at least 1
```

### Learn more:

- https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/master/docs/advanced.md

Comment: Thanks. Can yargs be used to document what such parameters should be?